# Interesting email I received?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

This email recently arrived in my inbox. I don't know how it avoided the spam folder, but it must be important. However, it looks like a dictionary in a blender... you'll see what I mean when you read it.

> From: owttrapnisretteltsrif@gmail.com
>
> 1. maglev verdant jumper phi impossible ringing greater everyone excellent harbringer acute quicken never vengeance eternal rocky resolute llama car rebuke electric knockback kangaroo flute exquisite solution refinery yellow jubilant illuminati infinite carats striking salutation nocturnal samurai illogical evergreen north glade empathy
> 2. swimming wretched evoke xylophone unburdened quiz equalize heathen civilized impatient escalate environmental toxic zoology nightstand temporal unfold zigzag requirement earthquake quest xenophobic extravagance mettle zebras magical flummox salt attempt tracked language greater backwards crazed axiom xeroxed variation very tried ytterbium conundrum nova vanquished vaporize fallout bracket jumprope sanctuary enzyme locket vocalization warfare garbled erratic rambling revenge grandmother galvanize
> 3. important must learning help information virtuous explosive iambic farfetched trapped hierarchy inside desolate toughness distinct revolution weaponized titanium bloodlust desecrate quadruple cage seventy five bulwark freedom flight miles castle rhombus transpose naive blocked southeast neglected

(end of email)

If any of you can find a meaning or message in this, I'd love to hear it.

Partial meanings are welcome.

Update: I've recently received another weird, puzzle-seeming email. I've put it here in case it may have some relation.

> From: maxhmaxktwwkxllvhfxl@gw.com
>
> 1. you may want to look for *lbyuoxmsbmvolyyuwkbuc*
> 2. make sure you know *jpnxfiayzjrvnvqauigmfvg*
> 3. No *ccmdym* can *omfsydrhjqglbcgefbnvgqakcwvrg*

Surprise, surprise. I got a third email. People have definitely seen codes in these, so I'm still not totally convinced they're a scam. Anyway, here it is, have fun.

> From: ylfmgbglnliild@gmail.com
>
> dsz gwlvhg svdl iwyllpnz ipsze vgs zg rhxrixf ozizmwsl dxz mr gyvy il pvm

## Mega Hint

Hi! One day left in the bounty, so I'm giving a really big hint. Hope someone can get it from this!

> Look for double letters in part 1 broken between words.

Comment: Hey! rot7 of the second email is "theotheraddresscomes@nd.jvt". Huh.                           Or "the other address comes @nd .jvt"

Comment: Have you considered just deleting what is obviously spam? :-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First paragraph:

> From the "Mega Hint", we are to look for double letters broken between words, i.e. a letter that comes at the end of a word and the beginning of the next word. (I don't know where this is hinted at in the puzzle besides the hint). Collecting those gives us:
> **VIGENERE KEY IS NINE**

Second paragraph:

> The email address backwards gives us "first letters in part two" (found by gabbo1092). This gives us:
> SWEXUQEHCIEETZNTUZREQXEMZMFSATLGBCAXVVTYCNVVFBJSELVWGERRGG
>  Then, run that through a Vigenerer decode with key "NINE", which gives:
> **FOR THIRD PARAGRAPH READ PRIMES ONLY COUNTING UP FIRST WORD IS TWENTY**

Third paragraph:

> Setting the first word as 20 and selecting the prime numbered words (23, 29, 31, ...) gives us:
>  **HELP TRAPPED INSIDE TITANIUM CAGE FIVE MILES SOUTHEAST**

Comment: That's it. Congrats

Answer (score 3):

## Partial Answer

> The email the message was sent from says *owttrapnisretteltsrif* which is *first letters in part two* written backwards

These letters are:

> swexuqehci, eetzntuzr, eqxemzmfsa, tlgbcaxvvty, cnvvfbjsel, vwgergg.

Alternative thought:

> first letters meaning acrostic style, gives : seetcv. It is also possible it is referring to the now added second email.

Second email:

> As pointed out by others the email address can be decoded with ROT7 to give theotheraddresscomes@nd.jvt. The first part in this email can be decoded as 'you may want to look for *brokencirclebookmarks*' with ROT16. No rotation seems to give anything for 2. and 3. at least not in there current form.

Still trying things out from there

Comment: Good spot on the first thing but your "These letters" isn't right. The last $X$ letters are not — but — any others?

Answer (score 0):

**Partial:**

> The first line of the second email says-
>  You may want to look for - Broken Circle Bookmarks (Rot16) , probably pointing towards a book called broken circle.