# More Email Shenanigans

Tags: mathematics, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

I don't know how these people know my email address, but after the (still unsolved) shenanigans of the [Interesting email I received?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72977/interesting-email-i-received) I got... yet another email. This one was of a Google Drive document that had been shared with me to comment on; I'm going to link it here in case anyone can find out what to do with it.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mwiVJlB9rlSbRmXpvOtWO0objtz7IQR75_seg429HmY/edit

If you want the diamond with the letters enlarged, I've got a separate doc with it enlarged here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oZs8GsnPtU7ePAz-MJHkgpsb991JYYxzcIS-QrKFveQ/edit

I really hope this stops or something comes of it.

As always, partials are welcome, and good luck.

Comment: Are the numbers in the grid correct?  I think a few in the upper right (specifically the letters) may be off by 1.

Answer (score 2):

Some partial progress

The grid is

> four separate multiplication tables, base 10, 16, 6, and 9.

The numbers below the grid

> spell out "You should check this document on a regular basis" with 1=A, 2=B, etc. (hinted by A1Z26 on the second page).

Treating the colored numbers

> as numbers in the corresponding base and doing the corresponding arithmetic, we get:
>  1 (black, left). 10
>  4 (black, left). 9
>  3 (red, right). 17 (or 11 base 16)
>  2 (blue, left). 5 (or 5 base 9)
>  5 (green, right). 19 (or 31 base 6)
>  6 (black, left). 80