# So, what happened is

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

So, I actually went southeast right away after seeing the answer to [Interesting email I received?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72977/interesting-email-i-received) and, when I had gone just about five miles, I'll be darned, I saw a titanium cage exactly as described in the email. There was a lock on it which allowed three letters to be inputted. However, there wan't a person in the cage. In fact, I couldn't see the other corner, but there was a paper that I grabbed... Here's what it said...

> **Pay attention to all of the classic puzzle clues, you'll be needing them... or not...**
>
> Hello. You may **n**ot know me, but I
>
> am inviting you to participate in the
>
> Heavy*s*olvers Puzzle Compe*t*iti**o**n,
>
> a highly secretive and **p**restigious
>
> n**e**w puzzle competition that to fully be
>
> intr*o*duced to you **n**eed t**o** still
>
> com*p*le*t*e **t**he second puzzle which
>
> eigh**t**een people **h**ave done so fa*r*
>
> twent*y* people are adm**i**tted max*i*mum
>
> remember: jlaxbcrl fir**s**t, cpme seco*n*d,
>
> you finally n*e*ed whozwq. re*r*ead if confuse*d*

Comment: Ahhh this is riddled with tricks! :D +1

Answer (score 2):

Partial "Answer" - Will Update Soon.

The bolded letters are -

> **nope not this**

Italics are -

> *stop tryin erd*

The acrostic says -

> HaHa nice try

However, jlaxbcrl,

> Is "acrostic" in rot17.

Also, whozwq is

> "*italic*" in rot12.

And cpme is

> "**bold**" in rot25.

However, an out there guess is "erd".

I probably missed something in the italics, because they're hard to see.

I'll also note that an s is missing in "However, there wan't a person in the cage.". I tried to email the person, but obviously it's fake.

There are many grammar errors, but at this point it's probably "or not..."

Comment: You didn't miss anything. I checked...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> HNT

based on Alto's work:

> First is acrostic = H, second is bold = N, third is italic = T. It's close to "hint"... Dunno if that means anything.